# Patch fails - No such file or directory but file exists and patch actually applied

Tags: patch

I created a patch from a github commit. When I run the patch (git apply patches/composer/github-25479-json-fields-support.patch
) it fails and says

```
error: Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd: No such file or directory
```

here is where it fails:

```
diff --git a/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd b/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd
index e3c54413f810..bb9136d8a9ae 100644
--- a/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd
+++ b/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd
@@ -20,6 +20,7 @@
     <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/texts/longtext.xsd" />
     <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/texts/mediumtext.xsd" />
     <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/texts/varchar.xsd" />
+    <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/texts/json.xsd" />
     <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/binaries/blob.xsd" />
     <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/binaries/mediumblob.xsd" />
     <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/binaries/longblob.xsd" />
```

however, that file definitely exists, has correct permissions and it *actually* added the new line. But still it fails.

Everything else in the patch also seems to apply, new files created etc. But it fails at build time.

[image: file modified]
Any ideas?

This file was actually AFTER the code above and also was created.
[image: file created with code later in patch]
[image: Before & After]

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Either it failed or it was executed successful. But it doesn't say that it cannot find the file but AND change the file it can't find. Please verify the source code you have before applying the patch. Then [edit] your question to include the content of the file you want to change, the command you execute to apply the patch file, the output you get from the execution and the new (or old?) content of the file you want to change. Keep in mind that you might need to use the `-p1` argument to get rid of the `a`/`b` directories.

Comment: I 100% agree it doesn't make sense. That's why I came here. But I assure you, that's what happened.  Even code that was further in the patch was executed. Just to be sure it wasn't failing somewhere else in the patch, I went through each edit in the patch and they all applied. I'm using git apply, but only after failing with composer update. Also, that is the next to last change in the file, and all other pointers use the a/b directories. I made the patch from here https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/25479/files